# SharePoint Online - limit file size upload

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file, size, asset-library

I'd like to limit the maximum file size my users can upload to a document and/or asset library. 
So for example they cannot upload any file bigger than 100MB. Where can I set this?

Thanks,

Ash

Answer (score 1):

No. The only thing you can do is set a limit per site collection.

[Manage site collection storage limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08)

Comment: It is related to SharePoint On-Premise. Is it possible to Set file size limit in SharePoint Online(Office 365)?

Comment: No. The only thing you can do is set a limit per site collection. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-site-collection-storage-limits-77389c2c-8e7e-4b16-ab97-1c7103784b08

Comment: Yes, We don't have control on File Size Limit in SharePoint Online. We need to ask this question in Microsoft support desk.

Comment: @Raphael You should edit your answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: There was no SharePoint Online tag. I will edit it now.

Comment: You could do it by adding a custom event receiver on itemadding with visual studio, although that's more a developer thing. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1043978/Remote-Event-Receivers-RER-in-SharePoint-Online

Comment: @RafaelBonametti thank you for your prompt response :-)

Comment: What about a form for "new item" that would check for the file size before uploading it to the document library?

Comment: How would it check? JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

For Sharepoint 2013 and 2016 [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34128.sharepoint-2016-file-size-limit.aspx) on the Microsoft website explains the maximum file sizes.